# ggplot2: Histogram with custom binwidth and log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, bin

I have the following code

```
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(test = rexp(1000, 1))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = test)) + geom_histogram(colour="black", fill="#FF9999",
                                                binwidth = ((range(df$test)[2] - range(df$test)[1])/10))
p
```

[image]

As you can see, I used a `binwidth` of a 10th of the range instead the default binwidth of range/30 (changing this value is actually recommended in the help). Now with this kind of data, a log transformation with `p + scale_x_log10()` works great, but when I try it with other variables (actually real-life variables and not randomly generated), I often get the error (translated from German)

```
Error in seq.default(min, max, by = by) : 
  invalid (to - from)/by in seq(.)
```

What does this mean? Am I using the correct and recommended technique to change the binwidth in accordance with the data range?

Comment: the "scale_x_log10" function might cause some zero-values by precision. Have a look at this [thread](https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/ML_for_Hackers/issues/6).

Comment: Indeed, using the native `log` function is a workaround (`p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = log(test))) + geom_histogram(colour="black", fill="#FF9999",
                                                binwidth = ((range(log(df$test))[2] - range(log(df$test))[1])/10))`), but still, this is quite cumbersome to manage. Shouldn't this be working and/or isn't there something else I am doing wrong?